# What exactly is my Common Name for a certificate-signing request

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub, csr

I'm trying to generate a certificate-signing request file, in order to generate a .p12 certificate for Azure Notification Hub so I can send push notifications. I'm following this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started#generate-the-certificate-signing-request-file

I'm just a little confused about the information I'm supposed to provide for the CSR.

User Email Address = I assume is the email associated with the account I'm current logged into the Mac with.

Common Name = This what I am confused by. The guide I referenced above simply says "Enter your Common Name". When I google about finding what my common name is, I see information about domain names and servers suggesting that the common name should be example.com. But I'm just trying to test push notifications with my Mac, I don't have a domain name...

Here is some of my search references:
https://www.ssl.com/how-to/csr-generation-in-macos-keychain-access/
https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-common-name/

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding APNS I'm using always the name of the private key in the keychain as common name.

Comment: Thanks, so you think it doesn't matter that much what I call it or?

Comment: Actually it's an arbitrary string but it's recommended to give it a unique name.

Comment: Ahhhh okay, so the answer here really is that it doesn't matter what I call it.